# segmentation fault as soon as i input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, user-input

I was trying to write a program on KARATSUBA MULTIPLICATION, but as soon as I input the second number it shows a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

I have not yet included all the cases in the program (just the one with both numbers having equal digits). I am very new at this so unable to figure things out using GDB.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int pro(int,int);
int digits(int);
int main()
{
   int s,q,r;
   printf("enter the two no.");
   scanf("%d",&s);
   scanf("%d",&q);
   r=pro(s,q);
   printf("the product is %d",r);
    return 0;
 }
int pro(int x,int y)
{
    int dig,a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p;
    dig=digits(x);
    if(dig>1){
    b=x%((int)pow(10,(d/2)));
    a=x/pow(10,(d/2));
    d=y%((int)pow(10,(d/2)));
    c=y/pow(10,(d/2));
     p1=pro(a,c);
     p2=pro(b,d);
     p3=pro(a+b,c+d);
     p=(pow(10,dig)*p1)+(pow(10,dig/2)*(p3-p2-p1))+p2;}

   if(dig==1)
 return (x*y);
}
int digits(int o)
{   int c=0;
    while(o>0){
         o=o/10;
         c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Run it in gdb and when it crashes look at the stack trace.  [bt full](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html)

Comment: use "-Wall" compiler-flag

Comment: "... am very new at this so unable to figure things out using GDB" - consider it incentive. If not now, *when* ?

Answer (score 2):

```
int d;
```

is not initialized in the function `pro()` and you are using it , using undeterminate values lead to undefined behvaior.

Please initialize the variable to suitable value before using it.

FYI the prototype of `pow()` is

```
double pow(double x, double y)
```

But I don't see double being used and you pass int to this API and store the return value in int so you might not get expected results because of type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

this looks strange

```
int pro(int x,int y)
{
  ...
  if(dig==1)
    return (x*y);
}
```

if `dig` is not 1, return whatever value is on the stack.

I would suggest, you compile with gcc and warn-all compiler-flag (`-Wall`).